# dataReceived in client side doesn't work?

Tags: client, twisted

I have implemented a simple server-client script like this:

Server:

```
class Server(Protocol):

  def connectionMade(self):
    while True:
      self.transport.write('a')
```

Client

```
class Client(Protocol):
  def dataReceived(self, data):
    print data
```

What I expected was a string of infinite a's was printed on client window, but actually, there's nothing appeared. When I replace the while loop in Server with a finite loop, it works. So it seems like the function connectionMade needs to be terminated before the whole data can appear on Client side? Am I wrong?

Comment: I am fairly confident that you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct.  As long as `connectionMade` is doing stuff, *no data has yet been written to the socket*.  `transport.write(x)` doesn't mean "immediately write 'x' to the socket", it means 'when the socket has some free buffer space, write 'x' to it'.

The example, as you phrase it:

```
def connectionMade(self):
  while True:
    self.transport.write('a')
```

simply allocates an infinitely large buffer full of 'a's, allocating memory until it crashes.